# Application Express node under Oracle SQL Deverloper v21.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am not able to see any items under the Application Express in SQL Developer v21.1.

Can you please help?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/apex/sql-dev-integration.html) says:

> Within SQL Developer, when you expand a connection whose schema owns any Application Express applications, you will see a node named Application Express. Further expanding this node will display a list of all the applications owned by that schema. You can click an application and a detail tab will display with all the application-level details. This includes Lists of Values, Lists, Templates, Tabs, etc. You can expand any application and you will see a list of the pages that make up that application. Clicking a page displays a detail tab with all the page-level details. This includes Regions, Items, Buttons, Processes, etc.

Which means that user you're currently connected to in SQL Developer doesn't have any Apex applications so - there's nothing to display.

Comment: I have 16 APEX applications installed on my APEX schema and Oracle pluggable DB. I am trying to connect with the SYS DBA user. How come I am not able to see my APEX 16 apps from SQL Developer?

Comment: Because you didn't create any Apex applications whose underlying database schema is SYS.